# How do I open a *.app file in linux terminal?

Tags: linux, file-format

I am trying to run the xeoma app provided as xeoma.app in Linux via terminal so I can run some switches but Linux keeps telling me `xeoma.app: command not found`.

The general term "app" is flooding my search results and making this difficult to research.

Documentation:
https://felenasoft.com/xeoma/en/help/commands/

Comment: Assuming it is in your `$PATH` then just running `Xeoma.app` followed by the list of arguments

Comment: Or if you are in the correct directory/path of the xeoma.app you can type something like `./xeoma.app` and that will ensure you are running the xeoma on the current path.

Comment: I am in the correct folder when trying to run it.

Comment: run `ls -al ./xeoma.app` to see if it's a directory or not? If yes then probably it's a Mac app. If it's a file then check if it has the execute bit or not

Comment: The documentation states `Xeoma.app` with a capital `X`. Linux is case-sensitive in general.